# Editable Combobox No Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ComboBox` that has `IsReadOnly="False"` and `IsEditable="True"` set.  When I click into the combobox and try to right click so that I get the paste option, no context menu at all comes up.  However, if I select an item from the combobox and THEN right click, the default context menu with copy/paste/cut shows up.  Is there a way to enable the context menu in the combobox before having to select an item?

Comment: Interesting question; if I were around my compiler right now I'd look at this. But maybe a workaround (until someone more knowledgable than me can answer) would be to select the first item in the combo box by default? I imagine your `SelectedItem` is empty/null and it doesn't remove that first blank element until you select an item.

Comment: This would work, but if the user deletes the content and then tries to right click and paste (which they will inevitably do), we're back to the same issue.